How to get the entire log in the terminal while running a robot file?
I am writing a PyQt5 application that integrates with Robot Framework to execute test cases. I execute robot files using run API. When I run a robot file directly from the terminal using the command robot example.robot
I see real-time logs displayed in the terminal, like this:
==============================================================================
TestSuite
==============================================================================
TestCase1                                                           | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TestCase2                                                           | FAIL |
Error: Expected 'Hello' but got 'Hi'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TestSuite                                                           | FAIL |
2 tests, 1 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  output.xml
Log:     log.html
Report:  report.html

How can I capture these real-time logs, including test results, errors, and summary, and display them dynamically in my PyQt5 application while the tests are running? I have searched through Robot Framework's APIs and documentation but couldn't find a clear way to achieve this functionality.
Thanks!

give 'robot example.robot 2>&1 | tee somelogfile.txt' a try

@ticktalk I execute test cases using the run API, not the robot command directly. I need a method to capture the logs dynamically, similar to how the robot command displays them in the terminal, and then display them in my PyQt5 application. Do you have any alternative ideas?

While its not possible to get the exact same log file as output.xml, robot does have "Listener Interface" that is intended for this exact usecase.
See documentation @ https://docs.robotframework.org/docs/extending_robot_framework/listeners_prerun_api/listeners
